# iOS MPMoviePlayer (resume playback after app become Active)

Tags: playback, mpmovieplayer, resume

I have App, playing Videos from web

everything works fine

but when user leave the app for reading email or anything

and come back the player gone!! big problem

so, I want user resume watching after come back to app

here is my code so far

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterforground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

the Methods

```
- (void) didEnterBackground
{
[theMovie.moviePlayer pause];
NSLog(@"Playing pause");
}

- (void) didEnterforground
{
[theMovie.moviePlayer play];
NSLog(@"Playing resume");
}
```

for know I use [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie]; NOT playing in view

should that's code works but, nothing works

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, edit info.plist.
Add background competence, required background modes, set category App plays audio

Try it!